# postgresql inner join and left join

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join

I have the following database structure, with postgres 9.5:

```
create table users (
  id character varying(255), 
  email character varying(127)
);

create table org_users(
  id character varying(255), 
  user_id character varying(255), -- foreign key to users.id
  manager_org_user_id character varying(255) -- refers to org_users.id; same table referential dependency
);

insert into users (id, email) values ('111', 'user1@example.com');
insert into users (id, email) values ('222', 'user2@example.com');
insert into users (id, email) values ('333', 'manager@example.com');

insert into org_users (id, user_id, manager_org_user_id) values ('o1', '111', 'o3');
insert into org_users (id, user_id, manager_org_user_id) values ('o2', '222', 'o3');
insert into org_users (id, user_id, manager_org_user_id) values ('o3', '333', null);
```

I have three users in my table. `user1@example.com`, `user2@example.com` are two normal users. `manager@example.com` is their manager. Now I want to display the following structure:

```
org_user_id, employee_user_id, employee_email, manager_org_user_id, manager_user_id, manager_email
```

I tried with the following sql query but it fails to work for me with `syntax error near JOIN`. Any help ?

```
select ou.id as employee_org_user_id,
    us.id as employee_user_id, 
    us.email as employee_email, 
    ou.manager_org_user_id as manager_org_user_id,
    u2.email as manager_email
from org_users ou 
    JOIN users us ON ou.user_id::text = us.id::text,
    LEFT JOIN org_users ou1 ON ou1.id::text = ou.manager_org_user_id::text
    LEFT JOIN users us2 ON ou1.user_id::text = us2.id::text;
```

Comment: `JOIN users us ON ou.user_id::text = us.id::text,` you need to remove `,` at end; also `u2.email as manager_email` should be `us2.email`; no need for cast to text (though it doesn't hurt output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove space, rename u2.email, drop the cast to text:

```
select ou.id as employee_org_user_id,
    us.id as employee_user_id, 
    us.email as employee_email, 
    ou.manager_org_user_id as manager_org_user_id,
    us2.email as manager_email
from org_users ou 
    JOIN users us ON ou.user_id = us.id
    LEFT JOIN org_users ou1 ON ou1.id = ou.manager_org_user_id
    LEFT JOIN users us2 ON ou1.user_id = us2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

This query resolve your problem:

```
SELECT ou.id as employee_org_user_id,
       us.id as employee_user_id, 
       us.email as employee_email, 
       ou.manager_org_user_id as manager_org_user_id
FROM org_users ou JOIN users us ON ou.user_id = us.id
```

---

#### Live example:

- http://tpcg.io/PuMym5

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I am accepting the other answer as that was marginally earlier. Thank you once again.